# how to activate different sections of code in a console application in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and have decided that creating a simple console application "Adventure book" (like a text based RPG) would be a good way to start immersing myself into the world of c# programming. I am having an issue with being unable to return to sections of code and to skip others. For example I am able to go from the start to option 1, but am unable to go straight to option 2 without it showing only option 1. Nor am I able to return from option 1 to the start.

I assume this is because the section of code for option 2 is below that of option 1. I could see some kind of activate/deactivate system possibly working by deactivating option 1 + the start and activating option 2 etc. I'm not even sure if that is possible, nor do I have any idea on how to do so.

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

```
string Nextpage;
        int Page = 0;

        //start
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Type option 1 to go to option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Type option 2 to go to option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Nextpage = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (Nextpage == "OPTION 1")
            {
                Page = 1;
            }
            if (Nextpage == "OPTION 2")
            {
                Page = 2;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        } while (Page == 0);

        //option 1
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Type start to go to start");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Nextpage = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (Nextpage == "start")
            {
                Page = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        } while (Page == 1);

        //option 2
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to option 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Type start to go to start");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Nextpage = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (Nextpage == "start")
            {
                Page = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        } while (Page == 2);
```

Comment: Is this the entire code of your game, or is this encapsuled in an outer loop?

Comment: This is an example of the system I use to change the pages. Eg, "option 1" and "option 2" are different choices made by the player and "start" is the page before. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
do
{
   //code
}while(condition);
```

use

```
while(condition)
{
    //code
}
```

The former snippet enters the loop at the `do` statement, runs the code, and then decides whether to loop or not based on the `while` "condition". The latter first assesses the condition and then decides whether it should enter the loop or skip the block entirely.

This should solve your problem of the code for option 1 being run even though you typed option 2.

To solve the problem of returning to the start, let the "start loop" encapsulate the code for option 1 and option 2 as well. See the code below and pay close attention to the curly brackets and indentation to see the order of operation.

```
string Nextpage;
int Page = 0;
while (Page == 0)
{    
    //Start code here

    //option 1
    while (Page == 1)
    {
        //option 1 code here
    }

    //option 2
    while (Page == 2)
    {
        //option 2 code here
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the great feed back. :D

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand control flow statements to get this working. `do {} while (..)` loop executes from 1 to many times so this is why you get "option 1" even if it is required "option 2". Check out `while(..) { }` statement which executes 0 to many times. Also it can be helpful if you put everything into some loop and manage some kind of list that would tell you what code executes when (`switch` statement) or use references to functions (delegates) (some kind of higher programming). I don't put any code here so that you can explore by yourself. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks heaps, your feedback helped tremendously :D